# Can you obtain scallops or see Pascal when playing in co-op mode?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I play Animal Crossing primarily in local co-op mode with other people in my house, and have noticed that we have been unsuccessful in getting Pascal to show up when playing together. I'm actually not even sure we've even *found* a scallop in several hours of co-op diving together. We've only seen him when taking single player turns, which causes us to break our sessions and play solo to see him.

Can Pascal appear when playing local (or online) co-op? If not, can you find scallops when playing in these modes, or was the scallop removed from the creatures that spawn underwater in co-op to avoid this encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on personal experience, you can find scallops during online co-op play. Every time I've found a scallop while other people were on my island, Pascal did not show up.

Comment: It's good to know that online co-op allows you to at least *find* scallops, but I think some of this is incorrect. Even in solo mode, the first scallop found does not always guarantee a Pascal visit. I've had an unlucky night where I haven't had Pascal appear until I got my *fourth* scallop. He always appears at *some* point, but you may have just been unlucky on that occurrence. Also, is there any evidence as to local co-op?

Comment: @king14nyr I don't have any evidence about local co-op, but also would be surprised if local co-op and online co-op were handled differently. From a developer perspective, that makes very little sense. Also, I've removed the speculation since your experience shows that my thoughts were not 100% correct.